# Is there any way to test a function in jest + vue-test-utils after async/await promise?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Helloo!

i'm trying to cover 100% of my file with unit tests, but I can't test a function in onMounted() that is called after a async/await promise.

using **Vue3, Pinia, i18n, Jest and Vue-test-utils.**

I have the following setup in the component

```
setup(props) {
    const { t } = useI18n();

    const activeTab = ref(0);
    const scale = computed(() => props?.data?.policyConfig?.scales);
    const counters = ref([]);

    const { getDocumentsProcessedCount } = useAnalysis();

    const {
      getConfigDomains,
      parseDomainLabel,
      parseDomainIcon,
    } = useDomains();

    const getRulesCounter = () => ({
      label: t('module.analysis.result.counter.rules.label'),
      count: props?.data?.policyConfig?.rules?.length,
      icon: 'list-resumo',
    });

    const getDocumentsCounter = () => {
      const domainId = props?.data?.policyConfig?.domainId;
      return {
        label: parseDomainLabel(domainId),
        count: getDocumentsProcessedCount(props?.data?.processSummary),
        icon: parseDomainIcon(domainId),
      };
    };

    const loading = reactive({
      scale: false,
    });

    const setCounters = () => {
      counters.value = [
        getRulesCounter(),
        getDocumentsCounter(),
      ];
    };

    const loadData = async () => {
      await getConfigDomains();
      setCounters();
    };

    onMounted(() => {
      loadData();
    });

    return {
      activeTab,
      counters,
      scale,
      loading,

      getRulesCounter,
      getDocumentsCounter,
      loadData,
      setCounters,
    };
  },
```

I would like to test if the `loadData()` function is calling the `setCounters()` function, so i did this test:

```
    it('Should loadData call setCounters', async () => {
      const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'setCounters');

      wrapper.vm.loadData();

      await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
      await flushPromises();

      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

But the spy function or `setCounters()` function is never called.

in my test mock I have configdomains

```
export const mocks = {
  configDomains: domains.data.getConfigDomains,
};
```

which is the data fetched by the getConfigDomains()

I did a test removing async/await from `getConfigDomains()` and it works fine, but causes problems when rendering the screen because it is necessary to have the information from getConfigDomains() for the `setCounters();`

Is there any way that I can test this situation?

Comment: There are no methods in composition api, you can't mock or spy on functions from setup. You have to mock useDomains.

Comment: I forgot to add this information to the question.
I have the mock `configdomains` which has the data that the `getConfigDomains()` function fetches.
I have edited it in the post.

Comment: You can't spy on setCounters. Assert the result of its work instead. I'd expect it to be normal otherwise, nothing specific to async.